# Steam market show all price for items dota 2

Tags: php, json, steam, steam-web-api

I want to get a list of all the items with prices from dota 2.
Using this code:

```
     <?$urll2 = "http://api.steamapis.com/market/items/570?api_key=******";
    enter code here$urljson2 = file_get_contents("$urll2"); 
    $data2 = json_decode($urljson2); 
    echo $data2; 
?>
```

And displays this error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://api.steamapis.com/market/items/570?api_key=4E465E3EC414FE37DAE8357EF7F01863)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Comment: *HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized* as it says, you are not authorized to get the content. Check your API key.

Comment: if I use API key for localhost, in steam i must take it to localhost or not?

Comment: If you go directly to this URL it give me JSON response: `{"error":"Missing required 'api_key' parameter."}`. After `570` put a question mark `?`.

Comment: i have it? but it does not working

Comment: Are you using your Steam API key? The one you got from http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey or are you using the one from https://steamapis.com/?

Comment: yes, it`s my steam APi key

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go to https://steamapis.com/ and sign up there. It's a third-party API so you need an API key from them, not from Steam. If you were using your Steam API key that's why it wasn't working. I would also recommend revoking your Steam API key as it's meant to be private (do so from http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey).

Comment: Thx, but can I do the same use the Steam API only?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can use your Steam API key with them as it's a third-party service. At the bottom of the SteamAPIs.com website you'll see that it says: `This site is not affiliated with Valve, Steam, or any of their partners.` For a list of what you _can_ do with your Steam API key, go to: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API